# Array literals in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

We have defined a vector as

```
A: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

when assigning a literal to this vector such as

```
A <= {'1', '0', '0', '1'};
```

will this expession populate the vector positions of 7,6,5 & 4 or positions of 3,2,1 & 0

The idea is a vector of bits which we can sign extend to an 8 bit integer but it will only currently work if the latter is true.

Answer (score 3):

Invalid syntax here.  If you want to keep the various bits as a list you can make the assignment:

```
A(3 downto 0) <= (3 => '1', 2=> '0', 1=> '0', 0=> '1') ;
```

Bonus sign extension:

```
A <= (2=> '0', 1=> '0', 0=> '1', others => '1') ;
```

Comment: That won't sign extend because it still only assigns the lower half of A. I think you meant `A <= (2=> '0', 1=> '0', 0=> '1', others => '1') ;`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Corrected in my answer.  I was getting distracted by the use of literals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is legal - at least it isn't in Xilinx ISE.

The right way to do it would be to specify the part of A that you want to assign:

```
A(3 downto 0) <= "1001";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using individual bits as a numeric constant?  Is there some reason you're not doing something like:

```
A <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(-7,A'length));
```

You can get rid of the std_logic_vector cast if you A is a signed type to start with, and you can use unsigned types and conversion functions if you don't want sign extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sign extension, use the appropriate type `signed`.

Then you can convert a proper number (like `-1`) to a vector of the appropriate width using the `to_signed` function, for example:

```
to_signed (-1, a'length)
```

Advantages to doing this over explicit bit setting are:

- simpler code
- everyone can read it and understand what you are doing (no comments necessary!)
- when `a` changes length, it all (still) Just Works